# Using apply in R to extract rows from a dataframe

Tags: r, apply

Using R, I have to extract specific rows from a data frame depending on certain conditions. The data frame is large (5.5 million rows to 251 columns) but I have given the code below to create a sample data frame.

```
df <- data.frame("Name" = c("Name1", "Name1", "Name1", "Name1","Name1" ), "Value"=c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "X"))
```

I need to skip through the entire data frame row by row starting at the top, and while skipping, when the value of the 'Value' column changes from X to Y or Y to X, I need to extract that row and next row and append them to another data frame.  For example, in the data frame above, the Value column of row 2 is X and that of row 3 is Y, and since the value has changed from X to Y, I  need to extract the entire row 2 and row 3 and add them to another data frame.

The result of the operations can be seen by running the code below

```
dfextract <- data.frame("Name" = c("Name1", "Name1"), "Value"=c("X", "Y"))
```

Currently I have used a 'for' loop to skip row to row and extract the rows when the values don't match.  But it very slow and inefficient.  The code snippet is below

```
for (i in 1:count) {
        if (df[[i+1, 2]] != df[i,2]) {
            dfextract <- rbind(dfextract, df[i,])
            dfextract <- rbind(dfextract, df[i+1,])
        }
}
```

I am looking for a better and faster solution to the above situation.  Perhaps using the functions belonging to the family of 'apply()' or using 'by()'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following does it. Note that there are two `lapply` based loop, in order to predict for changes in the values of column `Name`.

```
diffstr <- function(x) x[-1] == x[-length(x)]

res <- lapply(split(df, df$Name), function(x) {
    inx <- which(c(FALSE, !diffstr(x$Value)))
    do.call(rbind, lapply(inx, function(i) x[(i - 1):i, ]))
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
```

**How it works.**

1. First, I define a helper function `diffstr`. It compares all values of `x` but the first with all values of `x` but the last. Note that `x[-1]` is the vector `x[2], x[3], ..., x[length(x)]`, negative indices *remove* that element from the vector. And the same for `x[-length(x)`, the negative index removes the last `x`.
2. `split(df, df$Name)` splits the data frame into subsets each one of its own `Name`.
3. I then `lapply` an unnamed function to these subsets. This function's argument `x` will be each of the sub-data frames mentioned above.
4. That function start by determining where in `df$Value`are the changes. This is done with the call to the helper function `diffstr`. I have to append a `FALSE` to the return value because at first there are no changes.
5. The next line is a tricky one. Use `lapply` on the index of change points `inx` and for each one get a two rows segment of the data frame `x`. Then use `do.call` to call `rbind` those two rows df's and reassemble them together.
6. Now `res` is a list, with one sub-data frame for each `Name` (done with the `split`). So it needs to be put back together with another call to `do.call(rbind(...))`.
7. Final tidy up. The whole process messed up with the data frame's row names. To set them to `NULL` is just a well known trick that forces R to renumber the rows.

That's it. If you need more explanations, just say so.

Comment: Wow! This is genius!  It would help me a lot if you could explain the logic a little.  I tried my best but could not follow it!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`. `lag` can shift the row by 1, so we can use `Value != lag(Value)` to compare if the value is different than the previous one. `which(Value != lag(Value))` converts the result to row number. After that, `sort(unique(unlist(lapply(which(Value != lag(Value)), function(x) c(x, x - 1)))))` makes sure we also got the row number of those previous rows. Finally, `slice` can subset the data frame based on the row number provided.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  slice(sort(unique(unlist(lapply(which(Value != lag(Value)), function(x) c(x, x - 1))))))

df2
# A tibble: 4 x 2
    Name  Value
  <fctr> <fctr>
1  Name1      X
2  Name1      Y
3  Name1      Y
4  Name1      X
```

If the code is too long to read, you can also calculate the index before using the `slice` function as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
ind <- which(df$Value != lag(df$Value))
ind2 <- sort(unique(c(ind, ind - 1)))

df2 <- df %>% slice(ind2)
df2
# A tibble: 4 x 2
    Name  Value
  <fctr> <fctr>
1  Name1      X
2  Name1      Y
3  Name1      Y
4  Name1      X
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I ran this code on my data and I got 18693 rows but when I ran my original code I got 29968 rows.  Also, the number of rows using your code is an odd number.  When we are extracting pairs in each iteration, the number of rows can only be even.

Comment: @SureshSubramaniam This code works for the example dataset you provided. So there must be something different about your data and the example you provided. Moreover, your code is not working on your example dataset. For example, `count` is not defined in your code, so I was never able to run your code and I do not know what does it do.

Comment: @SureshSubramaniam Finally, I do not understand why the row number has to be an even number. There must be some rules that you did not mention in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, I would probably use an id for the rows and with `diff`:

```
df <- data.frame(colA=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1),
                 colB=1:12)
keep <- which(diff(df$colA) != 0)
df[unique(c(keep, keep+1)), ]

  colA colB
3     1    3
4     2    4
7     1    7
10    3   10
5     1    5
8     3    8
11    1   11
```

There is probably a faster option though.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a large dataset, speed might be the bottleneck. In this case `data.table` might be the best option for you.

Using the `data.table`-library, I would solve it like so:

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(Name = c("Name1", "Name1", "Name1", "Name1","Name1" ),
                 Value = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "X"))

# look if Value changes to the next instance
dt[, idx := Value != shift(Value, 1, fill = dt$Value[1])]

# filter the rows where the index changes and the next value
# and deselect the variable idx
dt[idx | shift(idx, 1)][, .(Name, Value)]
#>     Name Value
#> 1: Name1     Y
#> 2: Name1     Y
#> 3: Name1     X
```

Why does it give an odd-number and not an even-number?

Well, that is because in your data example, the last row should be selected as it changes, but there is no next row to select as well.